# A continuous function with a finite image must be constant

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, connectedness

I was recently tasked to prove:

> Let $f:[a,b] \mapsto N$ (where $N$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).  If $f$ is continuous and takes a finite number of values (that is $\{f x\mid x\in[a,b]\}$ is finite) then $f$ must be a constant function.

My first thought was to play around with arbitrary sets (as opposed to $[a,b]$), see which sets fit this statement and which sets fail.  If I could isolate the relevant property I might be able to see why this is true.  After a bit of playing around I came to the conclusion that this was probably true for all connected sets and probably not so true for sets that are not connected.  I was then able to come up with what I believed to be a proof that this property held for connected sets in general:

> Let us say that we have a clopen set $S$ on a connected set $\xi$.
>   Since the compliment of a closed set is open and vice versa, the compliment of a clopen set must also be clopen.
>   Thus both $S$ and $\xi \setminus S$ must be clopen. Because they are compliments they are disjoint.  That is to say $S \cap (\xi \setminus S) = \{\}$.
>   Because the clopen sets are their own closure we also know that
>
> \begin{equation*}
> S \cap \overline{(\xi\setminus S)} = \{\} =
> \overline{S} \cap (\xi\setminus S)
> \end{equation*}
>
> The definition of connectedness shows us that there are no $A$ and $B$ such that
>
> \begin{gather*}
> A \cup B = \xi \\
> \land \\
> A \neq \{\} \land B \neq \{\} \\
> \land \\
> A \cap \overline{B} = \{\} = \overline{A} \cap B
> \end{gather*}
>
> Since $S$ and $\xi\setminus S$ satisfy the first and last properties, either $S = \{\} \lor \xi\setminus S = \{\}$, that is to say there are only two clopen sets, the empty ($\{\}$) and universal ($\xi$)
>
> Given a continuous function $f : S \mapsto N$ such that the only sets that are clopen on $S$ are $S$ and $\{\}$ we can show that if $f S$ is finite $f S = \{x\}$.
>
> Let us consider a point $x$ in the codomain of $f$.
>   Let us consider the sets $\{x\}$ and $\{x\} \cup N \setminus f S$ (Everything in $N$ outside of the codomain and $x$).
>   $\{x\}$ is clearly closed on $N$ because it is a singleton, $\{x\} \cup N \setminus f S$ is open on $N$ because $N$ is open, and any open set minus a finite set is open.
>   The preimage of both these sets is the same because both of them only contain one point in the codomain.
>   Since $f$ is continuous we know that the preimage of a closed set is closed and the preimage of an open set is open.
>   Thus the preimage of $\{x\}$ is clopen on the domain, and is thus either $S$ or $\{\}$.
>   It is obviously not the null set because $x$ is in the codomain thus *something* must map to it.  So it must be the domain. 
>   Since $f^{-1} \{x\} = S$, $f S \subseteq \{x\}$.
>   Since $f S \neq \{\}$, $f S = \{x\}$.
>
> Thus any function from a connected set to a finite set is a constant function.

I have been told there is an error in my proof here (or at least I am jumping over some non-trivial step), but I cannot find it.  I was further given the hint that I was making a mistake in the way I set up the topology.

Where is my mistake?  Am I making any unwarranted assumptions?

Comment: You wrote: "Since $f$ is continuous we know that the preimage of a closed set is closed... " but this is not true. If $f$ is constant then the preimage can be open.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen This is the definition of continuity, I'm not sure how it can be false.  It is true that the pre-image of a closed set can be open, but closed and open are not mutually exclusive.  In fact if the function is constant the pre-image will always be both.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen If $f$ is constant then the preimage will always be both closed and open (either $\emptyset$ or the whole space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "Thus any function from a connected set to  a finite set  is constant." is incorrect.  It should say "Any $continuous$ function from a connected set (space) to  a $discrete$ space is constant.

The omission of "continuous" in that concluding sentence is, I think, a  minor accident.

The important omission is the dependence on the topology of the image-space.  The usual topology on $\Bbb N$ is discrete.  But if the only open subsets of a space $B$ are $B$ and $\emptyset$, then any function into $B$ is continuous.

The continuous image of a connected space is  a connected space. A continuous image of a disconnected space can be anything.

Comment: Thanks. You are certainly right that I missed the continuous bit in my final statement. That certainly is a pretty big slip. However I'm not sure I'm understanding your second point. It seems to me that every finite space is discrete. Could you give an example of a finite space that is not discrete? Thanks again for the thoughtful answer.

Comment: If $B$ is any set then $T=\{\phi,B\}$ is a topology on $B,$ and if $B$ has more than one member then  $T$ is not a discrete topology. Of course, for such an example we cannot choose $B$ to be a sub-space  of $\Bbb N$ with the usual  (discrete) topology on $\Bbb N.$

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I see now.  I think this is error is indeed the one my reader found.

Comment: Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1):

My reformulation of your proof idea:

First of all, your argument that $S$ is connected iff it has no closed-and-open subset $C$ such that $\emptyset \neq C \neq S$, is correct and a standard reformulation of connectedness.

The codomain of $f$ is $N$. The set $f[S]$ is called the image of $f$. You want to show that if $f[S]$ is finite then $f$ is constant, if $S$ is connected (i.e. has no non-trivial clopen set).

You take a point $x$ in the "codomain", you actually mean the image (!), so take $x = f(s)$ for some $s \in S$. Then you define $\{x\} \cup N\setminus f[S]$ which actually equals $N \setminus (f[S] \setminus\{x\})$ (why?), hence the complement of a finite set and thus open. You rightly note that $C := f^{-1}[\{x\}] = f^{-1}[\,\{x\} \cup N \setminus f[S]\,]$ (maybe you should prove it?) and thus $C$ is closed and open by continuity of $f$ and non-empty as $s \in C$. So $C=S$ by the fact that the only non-empty clopen subset of $S$ is $S$. and so all points of $S$ map to $x$.

IMHO the proof is a bit roundabout: just note that $f: S \to f[S]$ is still continuous and the image $f[S]$ is finite and (thus) discrete (this holds in all metric spaces) so all singletons are clopen in $f[S]$ (no need for $N$) and thus $f^{-1}[f[\{s\}]$ is clopen, non-empty and thus equal to $S$ and you're done again.

Answer (score -1):

Let f be continuous from a connected space into a T1 space.
If the image of f. A = { x1,.. xj } is finite, then
{ $f^{-1}(x1),.. f^{-1}(xj)$ } is a partition of domain f
into finite many pairwise disjoint closed sets which
contradicts that the domain is connected.

Comment: I now see that this is an alternative proof to the one I attempted.  The attempt is appreciated but I'm really asking what the error in my proof is, not how I can prove this otherwise.